# Couldn't get acceleration OpenMP

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, openmp

I am writing simple parallel program in C++ using OpenMP.
I am working on Windows 7 and on Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.
I changed the Language property of the project to "Yes/OpenMP" to support OpenMP

Here I provide the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h> 

using namespace std;

double sum; 
int i;
int n = 800000000;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{               
    omp_set_dynamic(0);
    omp_set_num_threads(4); 

    sum = 0;    
    #pragma omp for reduction(+:sum)
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum+= i/(n/10);

    cout<<"sum="<<sum<<endl;        

    return  EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But, I couldn't get any acceleration by changing the `x` in `omp_set_num_threads(x);`
It doesn't matter if I use OpenMp or not, the calculating time is the same, about 7 seconds.

Does Someone know what is the problem?

Comment: Be that as it may, I’m pretty sure there’s a closed formula for this calculation. And in fact, you are probably missing a cast, because as it is written at the moment, all `i`s < 80000000 will be truncated to 0.

Comment: If you want speed, then rule No1 is to avoid unnecessary computations, for example in your inner loop replace `sum += i/(n/10)` with `sum += i*d;` and declare `const double d=10.0/n;` before. A clever compiler may optimize this anyway, but best not rely on that (the compiler may for example optimize to a division by a constant, which is significantly less efficient).

Comment: I would suggest that you forget about `omp_set_num_threads()` and instead set the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS`. Otherwise you might distribute your program with number of threads fixed to a much higher value than the CPU count of the machine where it will actually be running on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `pragma` statement is missing the `parallel` specifier:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h> 

using namespace std;

double sum; 
int i;
int n = 800000000;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{               
    omp_set_dynamic(0);
    omp_set_num_threads(4); 

    sum = 0;    
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)  //  add "parallel"
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum+= i/(n/10);

    cout<<"sum="<<sum<<endl;        

    return  EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Sequential:**

```
sum=3.6e+009
2.30071
```

**Parallel:**

```
sum=3.6e+009
0.618365
```

---

Here's a version that some speedup with Hyperthreading. I had to increase the # of iterations by 10x and bump the datatypes to `long long`:

```
double sum; 
long long i;
long long n = 8000000000;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{               
    omp_set_dynamic(0);
    omp_set_num_threads(8); 

    double start = omp_get_wtime();


    sum = 0;    
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum+= i/(n/10);

    cout<<"sum="<<sum<<endl;       

    double end = omp_get_wtime(); 
    cout << end - start << endl;
    system("pause");

    return  EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Threads: 1**

```
sum=3.6e+014
13.0541
```

**Threads: 2**

```
sum=3.6e+010
6.62345
```

**Threads: 4**

```
sum=3.6e+010
3.85687
```

**Threads: 8**

```
sum=3.6e+010
3.285
```

Comment: very niche! I got acceleration in time!)

Comment: @NurlanKenzhebekov I've updated my answer with a version that shows some Hyperthreading speedup on my own quad-core Core i7 machine. It still isn't 4x, but 8 threads shows some improvement over 4 threads.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the error pointed out by Mystical, you seemed to assume that openMP can justs to magic. It can **at best use all cores** on your machine. If you have 2 cores, it may reduce the execution time by two if you call `omp_set_num_threads(np)` with np>=2, but for np much larger than the number of cores, the code will be inefficient due to parallelization overheads.

The example from Mystical was apparently run on at least 4 cores with np=4.

Comment: My machine has 4 physical cores and it supports 8 threads because in task manager I see 8 columns of CPU loading. But even if I set np=8 I couldn't get acceleration more than 3.9...Can you explain why I couldn't get acceleration more than 4 even I have 8 columns of CPU loading?

Comment: @NurlanKenzhebekov That's because Hyperthreading isn't useful in this particular example. From what I've seen before, code that runs mostly integer divisions don't benefit much (if at all) from Hyperthreading.

Comment: @Nurlan yes, your code is limited by computations not data loading and storing, so more threads than cores doesn't help. If you're code were data-limited, then each thread did little computations most of the time and hyperthreading would be benefitial.